# quicksort Mips assembly

Tags: assembly, recursion, mips, quicksort

So, I have a class where we've been handed an implementation of the quicksort algorithm in c code, and we have to make an implentation of that code in mips assembly language. I have succesfully made most of my code, but am having trouble with some of the recursion. This is the part of the c program that i'm concerned about:

```
...
tmp = v[left];
v[left] = v[last];
v[last] = tmp;
qsort(v, left, last-1);
qsort(v, last+1, right);
```

The part i'm having trouble with, is the recursive part, ie. qsort(v, left, last-1)...

My question is, when qsort(v, left, last-1) is run, the value last-1 is saved as "right". So when that recursive call is done, I have to recall the previous value(s) of "right". How could I do that, simply?

Edit:
the problem is, the bigger the list of numbers is, the more recursive calls there'll be, and as such, the more values i have to store. I guess, what I want to know, is if there's a way to store and recall a variable length of values?

Comment: Put it in a spare register?  Put it somewhere on the stack?

Comment: Using [the stack](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html) seems appropriate for a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

If you code your qsort function according to the standard [MIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS) calling convention, you can store the `right` variable in one of the callee-saved registers (`$s0,$1,...,$s7`).

When the `qsort` function starts executing, the first thing it should do is save whichever of the callee-saved registers that it uses onto the stack.